# Overloading operator= for structs, within classes

Tags: c++, struct, operator-overloading

We have the following:
(pseudoish)

```
class MyClass
{
    private:
       struct MyStruct{
          MyStruct operator=(const MyOtherStruct& rhs);
          int am1;
          int am2;
       };
};
```

We'd like to overload the `=` operator in the MyClass.cpp to do something like:

```
MyStruct&
MyStruct::operator=(const MyOtherStruct& rhs)
{
   am1 = rhs.am1;
   am2 = rhs.am2;
}
```

However, it doesn't want to compile. We're getting an error similar to

> "missing ; before &"

and

> "MyStruct must be a class or namespace if followed by ::"

Is there some concept here I'm missing?

Comment: Why have you got 2 return types on your operator= function?

Comment: You're missing qualification. There's no `MyStruct` outside of the class.

Comment: There is no `MyStruct::operator=` since it's inside `MyClass`. Use `MyClass::MyStruct::operator=`. Also, don't forget to declare `operator=` in `MyStruct`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move your `operator=` for `MyStruct` into the struct declaration body:

```
class MyClass
{
    private:
       struct MyStruct{
          int am1;
          int am2;

          MyStruct& operator=(const MyOtherStruct& rhs)
          {
             am1 = rhs.am1;
             am2 = rhs.am2;
             return *this;
          }
       };
};
```

Or if that's not possible because `MyOtherStruct` is incomplete or don't want to clutter the class declaration:

```
class MyClass
{
    private:
       struct MyStruct{
          int am1;
          int am2;

          MyStruct& operator=(const MyOtherStruct& rhs);
       };
};

inline MyClass::MyStruct& MyClass::MyStruct::operator=(const MyOtherStruct& rhs)
{
    am1 = rhs.am1;
    am2 = rhs.am2;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I had to comment on what I actually saw. ;)

Comment: why do we use `inline` here? Is it required?

Comment: @ctote If it's in the header it is. Otherwise you'll get multiple definition errors. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is

```
MyStruct& operator=(const MyOtherStruct& rhs) {
   // assignment logic goes here
   return *this;
}
```

for an operator directly within the body of `MyStruct`. Also note that I added the idiomatic `return *this` to let the assignment return a reference to this object.

**EDIT** in response to OP editing the question.
You can also declare the operator in the body, and define it somewhere else. In this case, the syntax is:

```
MyClass::MyStruct& MyClass::MyStruct::operator=(const MyOtherStruct& rhs) {
   // assignment logic goes here
   return *this;
}
```